# Is there a word meaning "easy to misidentify"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, vocabulary

It seems like there is a word for this, and the sense is not exactly "hard to identify" but specifically "easy to misidentify". If no such word exists, a word for "hard to identify" could suffice.

Comment: "Ambiguous" would come close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might go with either deceptive or delusive but would need a little more context.  You could probably do a thesaurus search on 'deceptive' and find the word that suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks! I think 'delusive' may be closest to what I'm getting at, that led me to 'specious', but i think delusive better focuses on the act of being misled whereas 'specious' focuses on the misled interpretation itself.

Answer (score 1):

Not explicitly about identification per se, but *misleading* might be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go with *mistakable*.

*from WordNet 3.0 Copyright 2006 by Princeton University. All rights reserved.*

**adj. so similar as to be easily identified for another thing**

Answer (score 0):

Something that is easily mistaken, or hard to identify, often lacks definition, distinction, or clarity and could, therefore, be considered "amorphous".

> **amorphous** *adjective*:
>
> without a clearly defined shape or form. "*amorphous* blue forms and straight black lines"
>
> **synonyms**: shapeless, formless, structureless, indeterminate
>
> • vague; ill-organized; unclassifiable. "make explicit the *amorphous* statements"
>
> • (of a group of people or an organization) lacking a clear structure or focus.
>   "an amorphous and leaderless legislature" Google [**amorphous**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=immorphous+definition&gws_rd=ssl)